# Inclusion of diffeomorphic disks enough to produce isotopy? (in Euclidean space)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two open disks embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that we have an inclusion $D_1 \hookrightarrow D_2$. Both $D_1 \stackrel{f_1}{\cong} D $ and $D_2 \stackrel{f_2}{\cong} D$ are diffeomorphic to the same open disk $D$. Is it then possible to produce an isotopy between the inclusion and the composition $f_2^{-1}\circ f_1$?

The only way I know how to produce isotopies is by a linear function, but in this situation this will not always give an embedding for each $t\in [0,1]$ (I have a simple illustration for $n=2$ I can include if it's helpful).

Any pointers to what I could try/where to look are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can construct an isotopy  with [Alexander's trick](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/412926_3d39652e92a9436da3228ddd5394f5c0.html) by adding as hypothesis $f_2^{-1}\circ{f_1}|_{\partial{D_1}}=i|_{\partial{D_1}}$.

$\textbf{Alexander's Trick.}$ Let $f,g : D^n \longrightarrow{D^n}$ be two homeomorphism between the $n$-dimensional closed disk in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in{\partial}D^n=S^{n-1}$, then $f$ is isotopic to $g$.

In particular, an isotopy between $f$ and $id_{D^n}$, such that $f|_{\partial{D^n}}=id_{\partial{D^n}}$, is given by
$$H:D^n\times[0,1]\longrightarrow{D}^n\qquad
H(x,t)=
    \begin{cases}
        t{\cdot}f(\frac{x}{t}) & 0\leq||x||<t\\
        x & t\leq||x||\leq1
    \end{cases}$$

Comment: The hypothesis is unfortunately too strong for the kind of situation I have in mind. I really want an inclusion where $D_1$ is a subset of $D_2$, which cannot be the case with this extra condition. But thanks for the pointer anyway!